# how to preserve filter values after opertion on grid

Tags: asp.net

I have some filter and one grid.And grid have some buttons like modify/edit.I am selecting some value from filters and getting some result in grid.now i want to modify some record.when i come again on grid data in filter should be remain same.

There is two pages.
one contain filters and grid
second contain modify details.

Thanks 
Pankaj Pareek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you need to store the selected filter values in Session, and reapply them when you re-render the page containing the filters. Or you could append some identifying details in the query string, but Session is the best way to go.

---

Edit: some useful links

- [MSDN: ASP.NET Session State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972429%28v=msdn.10%29)
- [Wikipedia: Session state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Session_state)
- [ASP.NET Session State: Architectural and Performance Considerations](https://web.archive.org/web/20151005225330/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2003/11/21/57453.aspx)

Comment: thx,Could u tell me better way to use session beacuse session will heavy my application.

Comment: Using Session will add virtually zero overhead to your application, it is already in operation if you are using ASP.NET. In fact you can use it to cache frequently used data and speed up your application. Check my edit for a few links to get you started.